# Adding a count and an index in my LinkedList

Tags: python, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I need to add an index and a count function for my program but I am really confused on how to go about this because my teacher is very broad. Any ideas that I could do for adding an index and a count function into my Linked List?
Here's my code:

```
    from ListNode import ListNode

    class LinkedList(object):

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self, seq=()):

        """ Pre: Creates a Linked List
        Post: Creates a list containing the items in the seq=()"""

        if seq == ():

            # If there is no items to be put into the list, then it creates an empty one.
            self.head = None

        else:

            # Creates a node for the first item.
            self.head = ListNode(seq[0], None)

            # If there are remaining items, then they're added while keeping track of the last node.
            last = self.head
            for item in seq[1:]:
                last.link = ListNode(item, None)
                last = last.link

        self.size = len(seq)

    #-------------------------------------------------------------

    def __len__(self):

        '''Pre: Nothing.
           Post: Returns the number of items in the list.'''

        return self.size

    #-------------------------------------------------------------

    def _find(self, position):

        '''This is a private method, which means it only works in this class.
        This returns the last node used. (0 is the first item, size-1 is the last item)
        Pre: 0 (less than or equal to) position (less than) self.size
        Post: Returns the ListNode at the specified position in the list.'''

        assert 0 <= position < self.size

        node = self.head
        # move forward until we reach the specified node
        for i in range(position):
            node = node.link
            return node

    #-------------------------------------------------------------

    def append(self,x):

        '''This adds (Appends) 'x' onto the end of the list
        Post: X is appended to the end of the list.'''

        # First create a new node containing x
        newNode = ListNode(x)

        # This will link it onto the end of the list.

        if self.head is not None:
            # Not an empty list
            node = self._find(self.size - 1)
            node.link = newNode

        else:
            # If it is an empty list.
            # You will set self.head to the new node
            self.head = newNode
        self.size += 1

    #-------------------------------------------------------------

    def __getitem__(self, position):

        ''' returns the data item at the location position
        Pre: 0 <= position < size
        Post: Returns data item at the specified position.'''

        node = self._find(position)
        return node.item

    #-------------------------------------------------------------

    def __setitem__(self, position, value):

        ''' Sets the data item at the location position to the value.
        Pre: 0 <= position < self.size
        Post: Sets the data item at the specified position to value.'''

        node = self._find(position)
        node.item = value

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def __delitem__(self, position):

        ''' Deletes the item at the location position from the list.
        Pre: 0 <= position < self.size
        Post: The item at the specified position is removed from the list.'''

        assert 0 <= position < self.size

        self._delete(position)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

       def __max__(self):

            ''' Goes through each node and compares what the max is for the linked list.
            Post: Finds the max of the linked list and returns that value.'''

            max_value = self.head.item
            node = self.head.next
            while node is not None:
                if node.item > max_value:
                    max_value = node.item
                node = node.link
            return max_value

        #--------------------------------------------------------------

        def __min__(self):

            ''' Goes through each node and compares what the min is for the linked list.
            Post: Finds the min of the linked list and returns that value.'''

            min_value = self.head.item
            node = self.head.next
            while node is not None:
                if node.item < min_value:
                    min_value = node.item
                node = node.link
            return min_value

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def _delete(self, position):

        ''' This is a private function where it deletes an item at the location
        position from the list.
        Pre: 0 <= position < self.size
        Post: The item at the specified location is removed from the list.
        The item is then returned ( To be used with pop.)'''

        if position == 0:
            # Save the item from the initial node
            item = self.head.item

            # Change the self.head to point "over" the deleted node.
            self.head = self.head.link

        else:
            # Find the node before the one that you are deleting.
            prev_node = self._find(position - 1)

            # Save the item from the node you are deleting.
            item = prev_node.link.item

            # Change the previous node to go over the deleted node. (Example 2 goes to 4)
            prev_node.link = prev_node.link.link

        self.size -= 1
        return item

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def pop(self, i = None):

        ''' This returns and removes whatever is at position 'i' from the list. It is
        defaulted to return and remove the last item.
        Pre: self.size > 0 and ((i is None or (0 <= i < self.size))

        Post: If I is None, then the last item in the list is removed and then returned.
        Otherwise, the item at position 'i' is removed and returned.'''

        assert self.size > 0 and (i is None or (0 <= i < self.size))

        # The default is to delete the last item in the list.
        # 'i' could be zero so we need to compare to None.

        if i is None:
            i = self.size - 1

        return self._delete(i)

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------

    def insert(self, i, x):

        ''' Inserts 'x' at the position 'i' is at in the list.
        Pre: 0 <= i <= self.size
        Post: x is inserted into the list at position 'i', and the old segment
              from position 'i' (oldsize-1) are now at position 'i'+1 (newsize - 1).'''

        assert 0 <= i <= self.size

        if i == 0:
            # Inserting before ) requires changing/updating self.head.
            self.head = ListNode(x, self.head)

        else:
            # Find the item that this node will be inserted after.
            node = self._find(x, self.head)
            node.link = ListNode(x, node.link)

        self.size += 1

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------

    def __copy__(self):

        ''' Post: Returns a new Linked List object that is a shallow copy of self.'''

        a = LinkedList()
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            a.append(node.item)
            node = node.link
        return a

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------

    def __iter__(self):

        return LinkedListIterator(self.head)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

class LinkedListIterator(object):

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self, head):
        self.currnode = head

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------

    def next(self):
        if self.currnode is None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            item = self.currnode.item
            self.currnode = self.currnode.link
            return item
```

This may seem basic for you guys but I am struggling to figure out what my teacher wants me to index or count in this program.

Comment: You shouldn't post your lab here. Ask your TA or lecturer or your friends instead?

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to look at python's documentation of those methods:

```
[].index.__doc__
[].count.__doc__
```